# Change existing MySQL table inside NetBeans

Tags: mysql, database, netbeans

I created a table inside NetBeans but one column is wrong type, it should be char instead of int. Is it possible to change it or do I have to delete the whole table and start again?

I searched all context menus but can't find "modify"/"edit" option.

Comment: Don't know how NetBeans works, but the way to modify a column is to execute `ALTER TABLE tblname MODIFY columnname CHAR(128)` in whatever MySQL client you have available.  No IDE needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my suggestion also you have two options :

1) **By using Netbeans**, you could edit (change) the current mysql table via Command Execution.

2) **By using mysql ADministrator tool**, such as **MySQL Query Browser** *from mysql GUI Tool itself*

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

you can right click on the column name and select "delete option", then right click on the table name and select "add column" option.

Comment: Yes, but then the column is added to the end while I want it on previous place!

Comment: then use alter table to modify the column, or use a real database tool such as mysql administrator